# Anyone know of a good pattern library for game UI design?

Tags: design-patterns, games

I'm a big fan of the Yahoo! Design pattern library. I'm surprised there isn't one for game UI - or at least I don't know of one. Does anyone? Looking for patterns for leaderboards, etc.

Comment: Games are the wild west of UIs and still very much one of the few places you can let aesthetics trump everything. Sadly, that means there's a lot of bad UIs. A gaming pattern library project would be a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I agree. One more project on the To-Do list! ;)

Comment: You're asking for quite a lot here. Is there one specific area of game UI you want advice with? If someone posts a great pattern library for and Inventory system and another posts a great pattern list for UI Maps then who's to say which of those answers is the correct one? Can you be more explicit in your question so people have something directly to focus on while answering?

Comment: [Gamesui](http://gamesui.com) for mobile game UI design patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DA01 pointed out , Game design patterns vary wildly and there is hardly a defined standard behind how to best do things. But here is a collection of some of the stuff I found

[User interface design in video games](http://www.thewanderlust.net/blog/2010/03/29/user-interface-design-in-video-games/)

[Game UI Patterns - Flickr Link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/headorange/collections/72157621971763357/)

[Good Game GUI Design](http://www.doolwind.com/blog/good-game-gui-design/)

[Interaction Design Pattern Library for Games](http://www.helpyouplay.com/)

The unfortunate thing is none of these are really proper pattern libraries but can give you some guidelines into best practices for Game UI design

Comment: The expression is "per se", meaning intrinsic.

Comment: sorry, I had a feeling I made a mistake there :) but I wasnt too sure

Comment: No problem.  This isn't Latin stack exchange.  :-)

Comment: These are very helpful - this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks a lot!